# How can I implement Stored Procedure that accept dynamic search criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Suppose I have the below table ( TestTable ) :

> **ID , SystemID , UserID**  ( all columns are of type int )

I want to write a stored procedure that should accept a string parameter; its value like **((5 and 6) or 7)** to return all users that apply the below queries :

```
Select * From TestTable Where SystemID = 5

Intersect

Select * From TestTable Where SystemID = 6
```

and the above result is ***union*** with

```
Select * From TestTable Where SystemID = 7
```

SP must accept any combination like **(((4 or 5) and 6) or 8)** , **(((5 or 9) or 8) and 10)** .. etc

***How can I implement that ?***

**Update :** my issue isn't how to split the string .. but how can i make dynamic sql to implement it's logical mean

Comment: You need to define your parameter better I think. Is that `((4 or 5) AND (6 OR (8 and 10)))` or `(4 OR (5 AND 6) OR (8 AND 10))`?

Comment: What did you try? You can use the substring function to achieve this requirement. You cannot need to expect us to write the whole stored procedure. You are not going to share your salary with us right??:P

Comment: @AaronBertrand  the problem in how to implement the dynamic query after splitting it

Comment: Well, understanding what the input actually means can help, and if you need to define which groups of ORs/ANDs go together in some way, then that will probably have to become part of the solution, right? Since it changes the way the parsing will have to work.

Comment: @Sivakumar .. again my issues is how to implement dyanimc query to translate the splitted item in the parameter not asking for how to split a string

Comment: How can the value of systemid be 5 and 6 at the same time? The intersect in your example would return 0 rows, so you'd only get the rows where systemid = 7

Comment: @AmrBadawy : seems like now only you have updated your question. I will try to help on this.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA .. it's mean that i want all users that exist in system 5 and in the same time exists at system 6 .. is it clear ?

Comment: Can you show us what the desired SQL would look like? Sound similar to a problem I had which I solved using this example. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+(2008)/64248/. It does sound like it would make more sense to create the query in code rather than SQL as it will be less clunky. SQL is not known for its string handling abilities.

Comment: @AmrBadawy : you can have list of OR values in one variable as comma separated and list AND values with another variable as comma separated. use while loop by checking the charindex of comma every time and build a query with intersect for OR's and Union for AND's. If you need a exact query i will post as answer. But I'm a bit lazy guy:(

Comment: @CountZero that's what i ask for .. How can i wirte a sql query to execute what's send in parameter as i explain above

Comment: @Sivakumar that depends on the answer to my question. Putting the ORs and ANDs into separate variables may remove your ability to group certain values "together" - I'm not sure the OP knows what they want either, but I'm not convinced you want to split them apart that way if there is meaning in the way the values are grouped.

Comment: @Sivakumar your solution is applicable if all 'or' is together and all  'and' are together .. but i have a combination of any as in the above examples , you can have or then and then or ...

Comment: It would be more appreciated if you have updated your question with your expected query for the below parameter value (((4 or 5) and 6) or 8) , (((5 or 9) or 8) and 10)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'4 or 5 and 6 or 8 and 10';


DECLARE 
  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', 
  @q NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT UserID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = ';

SELECT @sql = @q + REPLACE(REPLACE(@param, ' or ', '
   UNION ALL ' + @q),
 ' and ', '
   INTERSECT ' + @q);

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Results:

```
SELECT UserID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = 4
   UNION ALL SELECT UserID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = 5
   INTERSECT SELECT UserID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = 6
   UNION ALL SELECT UserID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = 8
   INTERSECT SELECT UserID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = 10
```

Now, whether this query yields the results you're actually after, I have no idea, but I believe it meets the requirements as stated.

Comment: that's near to what i want , but i want resutls just return ID in select instead of * and in the same time check (intersect / or) must be on ( UserID ) ?

Comment: @Amr So replace * with the ID column and change SystemID to UserID. Seriously, this is what you asked for in the question, can *you* not change it to what you really meant? (As an aside, the intersection will never work - how can a row exist where UserID = 6 *and* UserID = 8)?

Comment: for example, I want all users that exist in system 5 and 6 at the same time .. but I want to show ( ID ) in the results instead of userid .. i hope my comment is clear

Comment: @Amr no, it is still not clear. Instead of telling us how you want to formulate an intersect/union query, and that you aren't able to change * to ID, WHY DON't you show us some sample data, and which rows you want returned for each of the as pile parameters. If you make up fake crap in the question but then can't translate the answers to that, maybe you should tell us the real goal instead of throwing garbage over the wall at us...

Comment: @Araon .. my last question in first comment is an additional question to you ( not related to the main question ) .. so i asked it here and not updating the main question .. is it clear ?

Comment: @Amr no, it isn't, sorry. If you said SystemID in the question but you meant UserID, do you really need me to change SystemID to UserID in my answer?

Comment: your answer is right for my main question .. i just asked u another question related to your answer in first comment .. that's all :) Overall , thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score -1):

Try this... I have little changed Aaron Bertrand's query.

```
 DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'(((4 or 5) and 6) or 8)';
    DECLARE   @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', 
      @q NVARCHAR(MAX) =  N'SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE SystemID = ',
      @paranth NVARCHAR(100) = substring(@param,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@param));
      set @param =substring(@param,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@param),len(@param)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@param))

    SELECT @sql = @q + REPLACE(REPLACE(@param, ' or ', '
       UNION ALL ' + @q),
     ' and ', '
       INTERSECT ' + @q);
       set @sql=@paranth+@sql
       if (isnull(@paranth,'')<>'')
        set @sql=@sql+')'

    PRINT @sql;
```

Comment: try replacing first line with DECLARE @ param NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'(4 or 5) and (6 or 8)'; you'll get wrong results .. please try

Answer (score -2):

You could use a CSV to Integer table value function inside your SP. You have to create the CsvToInt function first of course. Then you can use it inside your Stored Procedure to turn a parameter into an integer list. As pointed out this only suits the "Or" component of your dynamic search criteria.

You can use this in conjunction with `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`. Which will allow you to add sql as a parameter.

```
SET @myBaseQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SystemId = ' + @myParam
EXECUTE(@myBaseQuery)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE SystemID IN (SELECT IntValue FROM dbo.CsvToInt('2,3,4,5,6'))
-- use your parameters

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CsvToInt] ( @Array VARCHAR(1000)) 
RETURNS @IntTable TABLE 
    (IntValue INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @separator CHAR(1)
    SET @separator = ','
    DECLARE @separator_position INT 
    DECLARE @array_value VARCHAR(1000) 
    SET @array = @array + ','
    While patindex('%,%' , @array) <> 0 
    BEGIN
      SELECT @separator_position =  patindex('%,%' , @array)
      SELECT @array_value = LEFT(@array, @separator_position - 1)
        INSERT @IntTable
        VALUES (CAST(@array_value AS INT))
      SELECT @array = stuff(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')
    END
    RETURN
END
```

CsvToInt function taken from http://www.summit-pro.com/blog/2010/05/18/csv-list-to-int-sql-function/

Comment: Oh I see. He wants dynamic

Comment: my parameter contain a combination of 'and' / 'or' .. but your solution is applicable only for 'or' :(

Comment: if this is the input "4 or 5 and 6 or 8 and 10" how will it split ur function

Comment: Its not just split the input string and use IN operator

Comment: Dude the way you are passing the input to your CsvToInt function itself is wrong

Comment: @AnandPhadke Without being rude to me care to explain?

Comment: @Jeremy he is right, if you look at the requirements, they don't just want an OR across all values in the "array" - and it's not an array anyway, it is a string e.g. `5 AND 6 OR 7` - please read the question again.

Comment: @JeremyChild -- I did not be rude dude,I said pls read the post carefully.The input string will have AND and OR operators

Comment: I am providing an option based on how I dealt with a similar problem in the past. I may not be the right answer. Just don't be so negative. Please check my edit. If it still does not satisfy there is no need to be negative.